# CI3 Files Driver not writing session file to folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Okay so I a trying to get sessions to write using the files driver included with CodeIgnighter 3. I have setup my config.php (codeIgnighter) like so:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'I have set a key here';

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Sessions are written like so:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

I have changed the folder that it is written into to 777 permissions.
I have also loaded the sessions in the contoller:

```
  $this->load->library('session');
```

The sessions do save to a cookie, but do not write to the folder. I have also tried adding the url helper like another post said and this did not work.

I spent about 1.5 hours going through posts to see if anyone else had this problem. Most of them is due to not setting the sess_save_path correctly. I am not sure what I am missing. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use debugger

Comment: I am not sure if FCPATH will make any difference then APPPATH but you could try that

Comment: Not sure where to start with debugging. I am pretty new to codeIgnighter.

I tried FCPATH, but it tells me my config is written wrong and won't load the website.

Comment: Well I couldn't get it to work, so I went the database route which worked instantly. Thanks for the ideas everyone. However, if anyone happens to know the answer to the problem that would be great because I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.